# Using MERGE with properties via REST

Tags: rest, merge, neo4j, cypher

According to the sample code at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0-M03/rest-api-transactional.html I'm trying to use the MERGE statement.

But when I apply the following statement:

```
{
    "statements": [
        {
            "statement": "MERGE (p:PERSON { identification }) ON CREATE p SET { properties } ON MATCH p SET { properties } RETURN p",
            "parameters": {
                "identification": {
                    "guid": "abc123xyz"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "lastName": "Doe",
                    "firstName": "John"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

it gets back with the following 2 errors:

- { identification }

code:    42000,
status:  STATEMENT_EXECUTION_ERROR,
message: Tried to set a property to a collection of mixed types. List(Map(guid -> abc123xyz))

- SET { properties }

code:    42001,
status:  STATEMENT_SYNTAX_ERROR",
message: `=' expected but`O' found\n\nThink we should have …

Can this not be done this way (yet) or am I missing something?

Thanks for your help

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel,

I think you have to use SET differently, something like this:

```
MERGE (p:PERSON { identification }) 
ON CREATE p SET p={ properties } 
ON MATCH p SET p={ properties } 
RETURN p
```

But I'm not sure if that `SET` overrides all your properties. So it might be that you have to specify them one by one.

```
{
    "statements": [
        {
            "statement": "MERGE (p:PERSON { guid : {guid} }) 
             ON CREATE p SET p.lastName={lastName},p.firstName={ firstName } 
             ON MATCH  p SET p.lastName={lastName},p.firstName={ firstName }
             RETURN p",
            "parameters": {
               "guid": "abc123xyz",
               "lastName": "Doe",
               "firstName": "John"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, that solves the part of setting the properties. I guess that your second piece of code is not really handy. Is there any chance for a construct like ... ON MATCH p ADD|APPEND|OVERRIDE p={properties} ... ?  And do you have a solution for the { identification } problem too?

Comment: Another question: wouldn't it make sense to be able to parameterize the labels part, i.e. "MERGE (p:{labels} ..."?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've discovered a bug.  I've reported the issue here:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/975

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that MERGE needs to know the keys you will search on in advance. Passing a map of parameters hides this.

To achieve the same, list each key explicitly. If you still want to pass them all in a single map, you can probably do something like: `MERGE (p:Person {name: {merge_map}.name, email: {merge_map}.email})`.